# Importing/Exporting parameters from a text file into a batch process

Tags: qgis, batch

I usually work my batches in Excel or TextPad, and then copy/paste it into ArcGIS batch UI.

Is it possible to do the same in QGIS? The tutorials I've seen show how to fill the interface line by line, only. I'm using QGIS 2.10.1.

BTW, right now I'm trying to merge all seven bands of Landsat imagery into one multiband image file. I have 152 scenes with 7 bands each.

Comment: Why don't you use a batch file (.bat or .cmd) in combination with arcpy/pyqgis? It doesn't use any UI, so it'll be a lot faster too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess I don't know how to do it. Do you know where I can find a tutorial on how to do it?  Just googled and found "http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/getting_started_with_pyqgis.html"

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Here is a link to the Pyqgis cookbook: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ It's a great reference to all the possibilities the library offers and it'll help you with developing scripts.

Comment: Thank you Stefan! Let me read through it, then I'll get back to you.